# Python: sum elements in the same places of nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have some calculation results, which I'm parsing and sorting with a dictionary, the expected sorted dictinary item should look like

```
key: [[1,2,3,4]]
```

But it also may happen that it looks like

```
key: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

In such a case I need to sum the values on the same places, to get like

```
key: [[6,8,10,12]]
```

How can I do that with Python, supposing that I'm not sure how many data sets would occur instead of one, but I need to sum them in a described way in any case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use zip and unpacking:

```
>>> [sum(i) for i in zip(*key)]
[6, 8, 10, 12]
```